# AWS Cognito User Pool - read-only client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The question is already stated in the title - is there any way to create an App client for Amazon Cognito User Pool, which will have read permissions only? It's a bit weird but when I untick all the boxes in "Writable Attributes" section (User pool -> General settings -> Add another app client), it gives back this warning:

> All attributes are writable by default because none are selected. Select attributes to make only those writable

That's cool, but my intention was to create 1 trustable private client with all write permissions and 1 public read-only client to be embedded into the app. I managed to reduce the number of writable attributes to a single one, which is not so important for me, but this solution looks hacky. Did anyone manage to crack this properly?

I also tried to play with App client OAuth 2.0 settings, but had no luck. Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

> all attributes are writable by default because none are selected.
>   Select attributes to make only those writable

The service provider is basically constraining you to their anticipated use case. Currently, I think your solution is the only work around.